# Identify black component in Gopro 3 silver

Tags: voltage

[image]

Can anyone tell me what this component with a red square around is?

As you can see, the one right next to it is burned, and I would like to replace it.

I have attched a schematic of the Black PSU it goes to.

I gave my gopro 12v instead of 5v :(

[image: gopro mainboard]

Comment: It appears to be associated with the large IC with a logo that looks like 'CHIPSIP' - what are the markings on that device?

Comment: Looks like a surface mount inductor to me.

Comment: Can you zoom in on those three 'F' components? I agree that it looks like a surface-mount inductor, but I wouldn't expect those to blow up in an overvoltage/reverse voltage condition (at least, not at low voltages like 12V).

Comment: This question is not really on topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

They're surface-mount inductors. The one below the red square is cracked slightly, and you can see a bit of the windings.

If the schematic matches your board -- which I'm not sure it does; that's an application note, not the final schematic of the GoPro -- those three inductors probably correspond to L1, L2, and L3 in the schematic.

This sort of cracking is not unusual for surface-mount inductors. It is often the result of mishandling, and does not affect the function of the part. Given that the board was exposed to overvoltage, it's likely that the real damage is elsewhere.

Comment: Can i take eny inductor that fits and replace it with ?
Or do i have to find the exact data on this one to replace it with ? is the data Ohm or ?

Comment: The damage to this inductor is essentially cosmetic. Any real damage that was caused to your device by overvoltage is likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: propperly the AS3607 Voltage regulator PSU, it gets hot :(